# Nifi ExecuteScript Processor with Python engine not logging info

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I implemented Nifi ExecuteScript Processor with Python engine, I have pointed **Script File** Property to my python file in ExecuteScript Processor. In my python code i have used log.error('Error') and log.info('Hello') of which i am able to see only log.error in nifi-app.log file and log.info are not showing.

```
flowFile = session.get()

if flowFile != None:
    try:
        log.info('Info >> Python processor started') #1
        log.error('Python processor started')        #2

        applicationId = flowFile.getAttribute('http.param.applicationId')

        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, ModJSON())
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename",

        flowFile.getAttribute('filename').split('.')[0] + '_translated_response.json')
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile,"http.param.applicationId",applicationId)

        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)

        log.error('Python processor completed')
    except:
        log.error('Error while sequencing ')
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)

    session.commit()
```

From Above code line #2 shows error in log file but line #1 is not getting logged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the log level from `/<nifi installation path>/conf/logback.xml`. I think your processor log level is `warn` not `info`.

Comment: Thanks @Lamanus for quick response. Can you help me with **tag** name which i need to change for it. I have changed log level for     <logger name="org.apache.nifi" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogAttribute" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogMessage" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession" level="INFO" /> but none seems to show the info message

Comment: Then add this. `<logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript" level="INFO"/>` By the way, after you set the option and please restart nifi.

Comment: Changing the log level doesn't require a restart of NiFi -- it will pick up the new configurations after ~30 seconds. This is the only major app-level configuration that can be changed without restarting.